# How and where to update users data in database using SvelteKit in case of a dependency on a external API response?

Tags: sveltekit

I have very simple website with a local bank integration. Problem is - bank has "status" endpoint, that returns "pending", "failure" or "success" status for a transaction ID.
Transaction could take up to 10 minutes (usually 5-10 seconds, but max time is up to 10 mins).

My current solution is just put everything in `+page.server.ts` load function:

- check users session
- make fetch the bank API endpoint
- update transaction table with the response
- return result

On `page.ts`, I'm just checking status and reload current page with `location.reload()` until I won't get "failure" or "success". (main problem I won't have result of this transaction if user closes window while "pending", but I have cronjob every night to update such records in the database)

Ideal solution would be to implement socket connection, but it's too much effort for a such small project.
Also, according to a sveltekit's docs - server load functions should stay "pure" and only pull data from database.
What is a good solution in this case, do I need to move everyting from load to action function and fetch status response from there?